# How to use MANUAL_CLOSE in core config?

Tags: stellar-core, ledger

[The example config](https://github.com/stellar/stellar-core/blob/master/docs/stellar-core_example.cfg) states that "Ledger will only close when stellar-core gets the `manualclose` command".

On a new private testing network (ledger#=1), after setting **`MANUAL_CLOSE=true`**, I did `stellar-core --newdb` & `stellar-core --newhist XX` (also `stellar-core --forcescp`), but the stellar core network cannot start at all (constantly "Joining SCP").

Also failed with **`RUN_STANDALONE=true`**, so this doesn't look like a protocol issue.

Any help/successful experience?

---

p.s. No previous hands-on with `manualclose`.

---

Edit: 
The other config variables to change ledger close time `ARTIFICIALLY_SET_CLOSE_TIME_FOR_TESTING` and `ARTIFICIALLY_ACCELERATE_TIME_FOR_TESTING` work just fine.

Comment: Can you post your `stellar-core.cfg`?

Answer (score 0):

Did you actually try to run the `manualclose` command after starting up the node with `RUN_STANDALONE=true` and `MANUAL_CLOSE=true` ?

The "Joining SCP" status is irrelevant if `MANUAL_CLOSE` is set, and it will happily claim "Synced!" as soon as it closes a ledger.

Comment: Thank you with your concern. I was using `RUN_STANDALONE=false` and `MANUAL_CLOSE=true`. "Joining SCP" just means that the network could not even start..